# Почему при загрузке первого активити появляется белый экран?

Tags: android

Почему при загрузке первого активити появляется сразу белый экран а потом уже background этого активити?

Разметка activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bgSplashScreen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/splashscreen" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Код activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Window w = getWindow();
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.splashscreen);
        player.setLooping(false); // Set looping
        player.setVolume(100, 100);

        //player.release();
        player.start();
    }
}
```

Код Manifesta

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.buratinoapps.falling">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Falling">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Изначально появляется белый экран
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А потом уже фон
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А нужно что бы сразу появлялся фон без белого экрана.

Comment: без кода помочь сложно будет

Comment: Гуглите SplashScreen. И извините, но Вам бы позаниматься русским языком, читать Ваш вопрос больно.

Comment: @Andrew добавил код

Comment: @DENGIPAY это не код, а разметка!

Comment: разметка как разметка, ничего особенного вроде, опять таки вероятнее всего проблема в SplashScreen как вам уже  писали ранее, код где-то не так работает наверное

Comment: Так а в коде кроме как того что я запускаю звук и устанавливаю fullscreen нечего нету

Comment: приложите пожалуйста полностью код активности которая у вас не работает!

Comment: @Andrew Код приложил с манифестом

Comment: а если без старта плеера попробовать, и оставить в теле метода `onCreate` только  `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

что-то изменится?

Comment: нет нечего не меняется

Comment: Чтобы сплеш нормально отработал, Вам надо в теме атрибуты поправить. Иначе все равно задержка заметная глазу будет

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov Я убрал
<!-- Status bar color. -->
и добавил
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:scaleType">centerCrop</item>

Может ещё что то нужно добавить что бы задержка была меньшей?

Comment: Добавьте xml с темой в вопрос пожалуйста